# how to make a line as a pseudo element?

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

So, I am stuck on this one. In the picture below you can see what should I do. However, I don't really understand how to make those crossed lines between the divs.

[image: picture]

Here is the code I have done so far:
https://codepen.io/kaeses_developer/pen/wxyYdb

I think I have to create a :before and an :after pseudo element for .menu-item--large.

```
.menu-item--large {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    font-size: 36px;
    background: none;
    margin: 0 50%;
}
```

But how do I do it right? Or are there any different ways to make it?

Comment: Please post the relevant [mcve] code in your question, please don’t just link to an external resource and expect us to go look.

Comment: Try using css border, for example " border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff ". However you need to address the fact that your container has flex-wrap and it breaks down from being 2x2 cells. If you want to maintain a 2x2 layout, then first address that. You could do this with flex, but also maybe this is a case to use an html table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, I used pseudo elements as you wanted, and came up with this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ebi-igweze/pen/yqvQvv), check it out first and here is the code below.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a4/6c/6d/a46c6d2f5104ea715af56e5c60d57eac.jpg);
}

.menu-container{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 margin: 0 25%;
}

.menu-item {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 flex: 1 1 25%;
 font-size: 250px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #fff;
}

.menu-item--large {
 flex-basis: 100%;
 font-size: 36px;
 background: none;
 margin: 0 50%;
}

.menu-item:hover > i {
 opacity: .4;
 color: #000;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  .menu-item.menu-item--with-v-divider {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  
  .menu-item.menu-item--with-v-divider:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5e5;
  }
  
  .menu-item.menu-item--with-h-dividers {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  
  .menu-item.menu-item--with-h-dividers:after,
  .menu-item.menu-item--with-h-dividers:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width:  325px;
    height: 1px;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
  }
  
  
  .menu-item.menu-item--with-h-dividers:after {
    right: 15px;
  }
  .menu-item.menu-item--with-h-dividers:before {
    left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>menu 2</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu-2.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="menu-container">
  <div class="menu-item menu-item--with-v-divider">
   <i class="far fa-list-alt"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item menu-item--large menu-item--with-h-dividers">
   <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item menu-item--with-v-divider">
   <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
  </div>  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can indeed use pseudos but also background-image(a gradient and currentcolor might do).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a4/6c/6d/a46c6d2f5104ea715af56e5c60d57eac.jpg);
}

.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 25%;
}

.menu-item {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  font-size: 20vw;/* demo purpose */
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
/* add pseudo where needed to draw a line */
.menu-item:not(.menu-item--large)+.menu-item:not(.menu-item--large):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: solid 2px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

div.menu-item.menu-item--large {
  min-width: 100%;
  font-size: 36px;
  /* extra to draw lines */
  background: linear-gradient( to right, transparent 0.75em, currentcolor 0.75em, currentcolor calc(50% - 1em), transparent calc(50% - 1em), transparent calc(50% + 1em), currentcolor calc(50% + 1em), currentcolor calc(100% - 0.75em), transparent calc(100% - 0.75em)) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 2px;
  /* end extra */
  margin: 0 50%;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="menu-item">
    <i class="far fa-list-alt"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item menu-item--large">
    <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the vertical lines, I don't think you need to use pseudo elements. Just some more divs. We'll call them .vertical-line

```
.vertical-line {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

For the horizontal lines, we'll use pseudo elements:

```
.menu-item--large:before {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 30px;
  right: calc(50% + 30px);
  top: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.menu-item--large:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 30px;
  left: calc(50% + 30px);
  top: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Those 30px numbers above are based on me increasing the margins for .menu-item so it looks more like the image you attached. I also added `position: relative;` to the .menu-container to make the absolute positioning work. https://codepen.io/mlissne/pen/XBZybZ